# read and write raw data to a external drive

Tags: c#, raw-data

i want to read the raw data from a drive and save it as a file on the pc i also want to be able to write that file back i already know ways of trimming the empty space and i know you can do this in c++ but i need to do it in c# if possible i have researched and can not find anything that works any help greatly appreciated

p.s. im still learning c# and this is the code i tried but dk how to modify it to work

```
[DllImport("Kernel32.dll")]

static extern IntPtr CreateFile(string filename,

[MarshalAs(UnmanagedType.U4)]FileAccess fileaccess,

[MarshalAs(UnmanagedType.U4)]FileShare fileshare,

int securityattributes,

[MarshalAs(UnmanagedType.U4)]FileMode creationdisposition,

int flags,

IntPtr template);

static int FILE_FLAG_NO_BUFFERING = 0x20000000; 

static private void Main(string[] args)
{
    IntPtr InvalidHandle = new IntPtr(-1);

    IntPtr ptr = CreateFile(@"\\.\A:",
    //IntPtr ptr = CreateFile(@"\\.F:", // for SD card

    FileAccess.ReadWrite,

    FileShare.ReadWrite,

    0,

    FileMode.OpenOrCreate,

    FILE_FLAG_NO_BUFFERING,

    IntPtr.Zero);

    if (ptr != InvalidHandle)
    {

        try
        {
            //FileStream disk = new FileStream(ptr, FileAccess.ReadWrite); // doesn't work as well
            FileStream disk = new FileStream(new Microsoft.Win32.SafeHandles.SafeFileHandle(ptr, true), FileAccess.ReadWrite);
            Console.WriteLine(disk.CanRead);
            Console.WriteLine(disk.CanSeek);
            Console.WriteLine(disk.CanTimeout);
            Console.WriteLine(disk.CanWrite); // always false

            byte[] inBuffer = new byte[512];
            var x = new byte[] { 1 };
            disk.Write(x, 0, 1); // error
            disk.Read(inBuffer, 0, 1);

            for (int i = 0; i < 2; i++)

                Console.Write("{0,4}", inBuffer[i]);

            Console.ReadLine();         
        }
        catch (Exception e)
        {
            Console.WriteLine(e.ToString());
            Console.ReadLine();
        }
    }

}
```

Comment: Side note: If you know how to do whatever you need in C++ it should not be too hard to port it to C# - post working C++ code of part that causes you problem in conversion and your conversion attempt. If you just learning - playing with creating bitmap images from scratch may be safer/cheaper/easier to visualize exercise.

Comment: idk c++ have not learnt it yet thats why i need to do it in c# as its whats im proggraming in now and i have no idea how to convert c++ code to c# or add it into a c# project honestly i want the same functionality as win32 disk imager which is coded in c++ but i need to include extra data as mine is for specific things